# Is an x86 instruction length a whole number of bytes?

Tags: assembly, x86

Is an x86 instruction length a whole number of bytes?
I know it can be up to 15 bytes long, but is it possible to have for example an instruction that is 13.5 bytes long?

Comment: No, but in a number of instructions some bits are unused.

Comment: There used to be such an architecture (iAPX 432).  We don't talk about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the current implementations, instructions are byte aligned.  Please be careful about speculating in public about such an idea, intel has a history of making the stupid real (thus really stupid).